# Smoothing contours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, contour, smoothing

I've been working on plotting filled XYZ contours using ggplot, and I've encountered a challenge I hope someone can help me with. Here's the situation:

My data involves varying x (-10 to 10) and y (10 to 0) values at intervals of 0.2.
When I plot this data, I get contours that have some kinks and jagged edges. I want to smoothen these contours, both the filled areas and the contour lines.

[image]

My initial attempt with the loess smoothing method has resulted in a completely different plot, which isn't what I intended.

Is there a workaround or an alternative approach that I can use to make the contours smoother around the kinks while preserving the overall shape of the data? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the script I am using.

```
k_diff <- c(seq(0, 0.15, 0.01), 0.2, seq(0.3, 1.1, 0.1))

diff_90 <- theta_90_long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = k_diff) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 10, 2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 10, 2)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction = 1, option = "H") +
 
  geom_contour(breaks = k_diff, color ="black", linewidth = 0.05) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.3, "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.3, "cm")) +
  labs(fill = "K") +
  ylab("Y") +
  xlab("X") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))

diff_90
```

Using plotly (doesn't give any output):

```
library(plotly)

z <- theta_90_long$z
y <- length(theta_90_long$y)
x <- length(theta_90_long$x)

fig2 <- plot_ly(
  type = "contour", 
  z = matrix(z, 
             nrow = y, ncol = x),
  autocontour = TRUE, 
  contours = list(
    end = 1, 
    size = 0.1, 
    start = 0
  ), 
  line = list(smoothing = 0.85)
) 

fig2
```

Comment: Is there any way for you to share your data? Without data that replicates the problem it is difficult to test or verify solutions

Comment: The dataset is quite extensive, containing 5150 values of z(x, y), making it impossible to post here. Is there a way to share an excel file here?

Comment: Here are y and z values only for x = -10:

Comment: y: 10.0  9.8  9.6  9.4  9.2  9.0  8.8  8.6  8.4  8.2  8.0  7.8  7.6  7.4  7.2  7.0  6.8  6.6  6.4  6.2  6.0  5.8  5.6  5.4  5.2  5.0  4.8  4.6  4.4  4.2  4.0  3.8  3.6  3.4  3.2  3.0  2.8  2.6  2.4  2.2  2.0  1.8  1.6  1.4  1.2  1.0  0.8  0.6  0.4  0.2  0.0

Comment: z: 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.98 0.98 0.97 0.98 0.99 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.99 0.98  0.98 0.99 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.99 0.99 0.99 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.99 0.99 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00

Comment: Perhaps a Dropbox link or similar?